# Is python a good choice to build a desktop application?

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm wondering if python is a good choice to develop a desktop application for a small business.
Is it possible to build something using PyQT or even Swing + Jython ? How I can make a executable file at the end?

Comment: yes there are several comercial desktop applications written in python ... you use something like pyinstaller or py2exe to bundle it into an executable (I am not sure if the executable bundlers support python3 yet I know for a bit they didnt ) ... no idea why you even bring up swing+jython ... java is not the solution to life the universe and everything

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found Python to be an excellent choice for developing a broad scala of applications including desktop applications. I've developed in C++ for many years, and for parts that are really time critical I sometimes use it still, but for most of my code Python helps me get results much faster. There are several ways to get an executable. Py2exe is one of them, Cython another option allowing easy combination with C++ if you need raw speed, interfacing with 3rd party libaries or low level control of devices. It also makes reverse engineering a bit harder, if that's a concern in your project.

By the way, when I started out with Python I was very concerned about performance and (being a quality manager at that time) almost blocked its introducion in our company for its lack of strickt typing. I was wrong about both. Since especially the rich set of built in datastructures as well as many of its standard modules are written in C++ and have been carefully optimized, it isn't so easy to beat on speed and memory efficiency as one might think. And the dynamic typing (only recently introduced in a language like C#) proved a very powerful means to write concise, readable, reliable and compact code.

I don't have shares (since Python is open source anyhow) but from all the languages I've used in the past (Algol, Pascal, Modula II, Assembler, Basic, Fortran, Cobol, C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript) it's the one I prefer rightnow to earn a living with.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are looking to do.  I have done it and it worked but there are other questions that can factor in like who will maintain or update the code, and do they know Python.  You can look at cx_freeze for making a windows executable out of a python program as one of many options.